# How to make actionSheet in iOS with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I found a lot answers about making a actionSheet but no many of them bear the rule of ARC. Maybe that's because ARC it's just release? 
Anyway, I am following thenewboston tutorial on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlXQUQh7Sd4&list=SP53038489615793F7) and I put down down the code in the tutorial but it doesn't work. I tweaked the code a little bit trying to conform to the ARC rule but I got errors.

Can someone help me out with a correct example of making a actionSheet with ARC?

Here is my code:
.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
@property IBOutlet UIButton *button;
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Want to see an alert?"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yea, lets see it"
                                  otherButtonTitles:Nil, nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"OK, here it is"
                              message:@"bacon is good umm"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Here is the error I got:

```
2013-12-24 16:23:38.403 BaconUISwitch[4759:70b] -[ViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109238040
2013-12-24 16:23:38.407 BaconUISwitch[4759:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109238040'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010188d795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001015f0991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010191ebad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010187f09d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010187ec48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000100254096 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000100254044 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000100328450 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001003279c0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000100288c15 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100289633 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 988
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000100262fa2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100250d7f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9549
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010181cec1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010181c792 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010183861f __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101837f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001039943a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000100253043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    19  BaconUISwitch                       0x0000000100001bb3 main + 115
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101f1c5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: How do you call `buttonPressed:`? It has nothing to do with this code you have shown us. It is to do with the why you are calling `buttonPressed:` you are calling it like `buttonPressed` when it should be calling `buttonPressed:` notice the `:` on the end.

Comment: @Popeye  I linked the buttonPressed with that button in my storyboard. I don't think the problem lies in the linking. I did it a couple times and it went well. I think the problem is about the coding. thenewboston uses things like "alloc" and "release" and so but some of which are deprecated now. I tried to change it but I guess I did something wrong here

Comment: Well you are calling `buttonPressed` not `buttonPressed:`. This `[ViewController buttonPressed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` is telling you that `buttonPressed` is not a recognized selector for your view controller. So it is clearly calling `buttonPressed` in your code or you haven't linked it correctly. That are you haven't told us something.

Comment: @Popeye I just found the problem. When I modified the buttonPressed, Xcode automatically add some method in the storyboard and I didn't notice it. I cleared out the old ones and it works! Thank you for your help